# Multiple Countdown on Jquery PHP

Tags: jquery, timer, countdown

I have zero knowledge on jquery. and i feel sorry for that. what i want to achieve is something like this http://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Final-Countdown-Simple-Date-Countdown-Plugin/examples/multiple_clocks.html

But i dont understand the how the code works. I try the code posted on that page but it returns nothing.

Can anybody help me with this? any help is very much appreciated.

Comment: Check for any JS error. Have you included all the necessay jquery and countdown plugin files ?

Comment: You need to also include jQuery and http://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Final-Countdown-Simple-Date-Countdown-Plugin/src/jquery.countdown.js for it to work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to copy and include the jQuery plugin

```
<script src="jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="jquery.countdown.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

and provide `data-until` attribute like:

```
 <div data-countdown="12/05/2011" data-until="12/06/2014"></div>
 <div data-countdown="15/06/2011" data-until="12/06/2014"></div>
 <div data-countdown="20/07/2011" data-until="12/06/2014"></div>
```

See [fiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/U9LX6/)

Answer (score 0):

Basically there are only two things happening. First

> $('div[data-countdown]').each(function(i)

is a loop over all divs which have data attribute countdown.
Second thing is applying the jquery countdown plugin to each of those elements. This happens on this line

> $(this).countdown(toDate, function(event) {

$(this) represents each of the found elements. Not to forget as I mentioned it is a jquery plugin. So you need included jquery and jquery.countdown files in your html.

**Edit:** Including happens as this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24201881/2582496) states.